# How to get text with CTRL C

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get a text from textarea but I have a problem.

image: https://ibb.co/FDrWPhR

```
<textarea class="ac-ad-code-area " data-action-type="js" name="ad-code" readonly="readOnly" rows="4">

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MY0LW0Q/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;tag=tag-20&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=9325&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;creativeASIN=B01MY0LW0Q&amp;linkId={{link_id}}

</textarea>
```

I want to get a text like that:
"[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MY0LW0Q/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=tag-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&linkCode=as2&creativeASIN=B01MY0LW0Q&linkId=48af8f0f4418037b124d254b56586927](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MY0LW0Q)"

So, I selected and copied the text.

```
text_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ac-quicklink-ad-textlink"]/div[2]/span/textarea').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")
```

text_link is NoneType

How do I get this text using "CTRL + C" ?

I hope you understand the problem. Sorry for bad English skills.

Comment: your question is very confused. Please try to better explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why do you want to use `CTRL + C` at the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pyperclip` package for that:

```
import pyperclip


pyperclip.paste()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt method available you can use it

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ac-quicklink-ad-textlink"]/div[2]/span/textarea').getText();
```